ORA-65139: Mismatch Between XML Metadata File And Data File
I have two systems - SYS1, SYS2(stand alone). On both is running an oracle 19c database. I want to create a plugable database from SYS1 and want to plug in the SYS2 database.
I created the pluggable db in read only mode with the sql developer generated script:
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE "SYS1DB" CLOSE IMMEDIATE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE "SYS1DB" OPEN READ ONLY';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE "SYS2DB" FROM "SYS1DB"
      STORAGE UNLIMITED TEMPFILE REUSE
     FILE_NAME_CONVERT=NONE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE "SYS1DB" CLOSE IMMEDIATE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE "SYS1DB" OPEN READ WRITE';
END;

I copied the files (xml,pdb) via USB Stick (because of the stand alone) to my SYS2.
In my SYS2 system  I want to plug in the files with:
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE "SYS2DB" USING 'SYS2DB.XML'
  SOURCE_FILE_NAME_CONVERT=NONE
  NOCOPY
  STORAGE UNLIMITED TEMPFILE REUSE;

Then i get this error:

ORA-65139: Mismatch Between XML Metadata File And Data File "path/to/file" 
for value afn (125 in the plug XML file, 18 in the data file) 
*Cause   Either the XML metadata file or the data file was corrupt
*Action  Verify that the XML file and the data file are consistent as of the point when the unplug was done and retry the operation

WHen I fix all the afn values in my xml file (for testing reasons), I get this error:

ORA-65139: Mismatch Between XML Metadata File And Data File "path/to/file" for value createscnbas (455193957 in the plug XML file, 455205365 in the data file)

I also tried to plugin the files in my SYS1 database, and this works without errors.
I also created in my SYS2 Database pluggable files, and plugin them again in my SYS2 database, this works also.
Why do I get these errors, i am not changing files content, when I copy the files from SYS1 to SYS2.

@nbk what u mean? i copy the generated xml file to the other system.

i testet it, the xml was found, otherwise there is an another error. the ORA-65139 comes only when a xml file was found and the values are diffrent.
